# how do I show a div on page load with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have div x that I am trying to show when the page loads. For example if the url contains XYZ then it should load div 1, and if the url contains ABC then it should load div 2.

This is my code.

```
<div class="one">XYZ</div>
<div class="two">ABC</div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $showDIV = two;
    if($showDIV  == 'one' ){
        $(".one").show(); 
    }else if($showDIV == 'two' ){
        $(".two").show(); 
    }
});
<script>
```

I get the number from the URL, now, for some reason, this is not working at all.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Are they both showing? In that case, you need to "hide" the other one. Otherwise make sure you're getting the value of $showDIV correctly. - btw, you're missing a closing script tag.

Comment: In your function you assign "two"  as the value for `$showDIV`, so `$showDIV` can never be anything else than "two"...

Comment: Johannes I used two, just as a test. It will either be one or two depending on the situation.

Comment: are you classes hidden by default (using CSS)?

Comment: yes, they are hidden by default.

Comment: depending if you are using strings or integers for the value of the variable, the quotes are either missing in the second line or should be erased in the following lines.

Comment: Johannes: yes that was the issue.

Comment: okay, I added that as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $showDIV = 'two';
    if($showDIV  == 'one' ){
        $(".one").show(); 
    }else if($showDIV == 'two' ){
        $(".two").show(); 
    }
});
```

had to do the single quotes around the two.

Answer (score 0):

depending if you are using strings or integers for the value of the variable, the quotes are either missing in the second line of the function or should be erased in the following lines.